My account has become a Token Account, how can I solve it?
My account that I used commonly had some solanas which I left untouched for a while, now I tried to move my solanas again and it gives me an error and it doesn't allow me to make any transaction or send or anything about solanas and when I search for it in solscan, it doesn't It comes out as an account, if not as a token account and it is super strange, what can I do to withdraw or recover my solanas?

I believe you would need at least to share some addresses to take a look at.

4CASLGRDzSNKyx81hLeH6NdNjGAUX7GDJCZJbyoJcW82

4CASLGRDzSNKyx81hLeH6NdNjGAUX7GDJCZJbyoJcW82 WALLET

From what you shared the address 4CASLGRDzSNKyx81hLeH6NdNjGAUX7GDJCZJbyoJcW82 is a holder of the Wrapped SOL token of owner https://explorer.solana.com/address/SavR1E3cvckV6T2JEEM2T8bqeS8BzeiJ9NoTUUNaQwV
You need to unwrap the Wrapped Solana token into native SOL that can be then used in the standard manner of sending SOL.
So unwrap first - in wallet or at Jupiter

https://station.jup.ag/guides/general/wrapped-sol
https://help.phantom.app/hc/en-us/articles/4406389768339-I-received-a-Wrapped-token


Same happened with me, My account is also become a Token Account. and It's ownership shows someone else. please check details below :
My wallet :
https://solscan.io/account/J6XHoatXq1thecNCDirNZ9UuvF8irn6zE4ujsSUNWkTf
My wallet ownership shows someone else. This is also the address who stolen few hours ago all of my assets to this wallet.

Here is the transaction details :
https://solscan.io/tx/5a4KXU6oJngy5kNW1qppjLEvR9Sc5yXmTRiCnXbADRdD9dj1pAFMjwcwSVvoM9j8WDvMGkbYWb4pMwnYxYkok4qA
